# What exactly does the `systemLanguage` attribute in multilingual SVG's refer to?

Tags: svg, multilingual

The SVG specs describe a `systemLanguage` attribute (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SystemLanguageAttribute) that can be used to provide multilingual content (for example when put in a `switch` that provides cases for different languages).

But what exactly is meant with `systemLanguage`? Is it the language of the Browser? The language of operating System? The keyboard layout language? The thing that PHP's `$_SERVER[’HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE’]` contains? A parameter of the SVG file itself (like `foo.svg?en-US`)? What "thing" can/should/may I change to actually trigger the element with matching `systemLanguage` attribute?

Background:
I'm about to design a website that has a language switcher. This website will contain SVG images. And the SVG images will contain text. That's why I wonder about what the `systemLanguage` attribute evaluates exactly.  Can I pass the language that is selected by the user of my website to the SVG file or does it only work if the user actually changes some Browser/OS language?

Edit:
Just found, on Wikimedia Commons there is an example, where one can actually change the language with a drop down box: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SystemLanguage.svg, but I can't figure out how the language is passed to the SVG file.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox it matches your preferred language or languages set via `about:preferences#content` then click on the Choose... button

[image: Language selection dialogue]

Chrome has a similar mechanism as do other UAs.

Mediawiki are are displaying a png on that page, they display a different png if you select a different language in the dropdown. If you click on the png you go to a page with an actual svg file that you can change by changing your UA language.

Comment: So, there's no other way to pass the language to the SVG file only by changing teh Browser settings? I assume Mediawiki is "faking" the Browser language when it does its SVG->PNG magic? It woul be really great if I could couple the website language and teh SVG language to use the same mechanism (language selector).

Comment: Mediawiki are are displaying a png on that page, they chage the png if you select a different language in the dropdown. If you click on the png you go to a page with an actual svg file that you can change by changing your UA language as per my answer.