# Switch the display language of multi-language SVG (using systemLanguage) for display in browser

Tags: svg, browser, localization, internationalization

An SVG file can contain text in multiple languages (to be shown alternatively), using the `systemLanguage` attribute inside a `<switch>` element. See for example:

- the [explanation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/switch#SVG_%3Cswitch%3E_example)
- the [Multilingual SVG example.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Multilingual_SVG_example.svg) on Wikimedia Commons*
- [What exactly does the `systemLanguage` attribute in multilingual SVG's refer to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164086/what-exactly-does-the-systemlanguage-attribute-in-multilingual-svgs-refer-to)

This is very handy for displaying diagrams on a multi-lingual website: I can just include the image using the `<img>` tag, and the browser will automatically show the text in the right language, based on the language chosen in the browser settings.

However, generally relying on browser settings alone is not good, because the user might want to see the site in a different language, and requiring them to fumble with settings is not practical. So most sites offer a way to switch the display language. For example:

- on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn) there is a "Language" button at the top of the page
- the [Debian website](https://www.debian.org/) has links in the footer ("This page is also available in the following languages")

If I want to offer this type of language switching, how do I switch the display language of a multi-language SVG file? I found no HTML tag, DOM API or similar that would allow changing the display language chosen by the browser.

Or will I have to do this server-side? This is obviously possible, but rather inelegant.

The problem was also noticed by the Wikimedia project - see [T60920 - lang support for SVG images using SystemLanguageAttribute ill-defined and not properly supported in browsers](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T60920).

---

**tl;dr:** When displaying a multi-language SVG (using `systemLanguage`) in a browser, can I influence the SVG's display language without messing with the SVG file itself?

Comment: It doesn't look good. I can imagine a number of not-so-nice JavaScript hacks, but haven't yet found any way to directly influence the `systemLanguage` attribute.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Yes, that's what I feared. I'm suprised this is not included in the specs, it seems an obvious omission. Well, maybe not so obvious...

Comment: No you can't change the systemLanguage from a webpage, it can only be done by the browser's user.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to rely on the browser (as you said) you need to render the image anyway as png (for every language) and embedd it as PNG, as Wikipedia/Wikimedia does it. Expecially multilingual files are not fully supported by browsers and might render differently (between Chrome and Firefox and Internet Explorer ,...)

But if you want to embedd a SVG in a specific language, it does not make any sence to embedd it as multilingual file.